# How to pass data from one model to another model?

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, model

I have two different views each with a model to hold their data.  I'm trying to pass the value of one variable in the model to be used in the other model but the value from the first model isn't being passed.

First file

```
struct Number: View {

@StateObject var model = NumberModel()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Enter your first number", text: $model.firstNum)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            Section {
                Text("\(model.firstNum)")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Model for first file

```
class NumberModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var firstNum: String

init() {
    self.firstNum = ""
}
}
```

Second file

```
struct SecondNumber: View {

@StateObject var model = SecondNumberModel()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Enter your second number", text: $model.secondNum)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
            Section {
                Button {
                    model.add()
                } label: {
                    Text("Press Me!!!")
                }

            }
            Section {
                Text("\(model.total)")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Model for second file

```
class SecondNumberModel: ObservableObject {
@ObservedObject var model = NumberModel()

@Published var secondNum: String

@Published var total: Int

init() {
    self.secondNum = ""
    self.total = 0
}

func add() {
    self.total = Int(self.secondNum + self.model.firstNum) ?? 0
}
}
```

This is the content view

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Number()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                Text("First")
            }
        SecondNumber()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                Text("Second")
            }
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to get user input from the first file and then send that number to the second file to be added with the second number gathered.  But the value of the first number doesn't get passed into the second file's model.  Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You're creating a *new instance* of `NumberModel` each time you write `NumberModel()`. If you want to share the same model, you have to pass a reference to the *same instance* between your views. Because your code doesn't make it apparent how `Number` and `SecondNumber` are connected in the view hierarchy, it's hard to give a suggestion as to how to do that. Can you update your question showing how the two are related in your code?

Comment: So at the moment the views don’t have any correlation. All I thought I needed to do was pass the numberModel to secondnumbermodel and then use the values from the numberModel inside the secondnumbermodel. How would I go about passing the same instance of the view? Would I still do the calculation in the model?

Comment: "How would I go about passing the same instance of the view?" Not the view. You need to have a reference to the same instance of the View Model. And to do that, we would need to see how the two views are related.

Comment: Sorry I’m a little confused how I can show the relation. If I added screenshots of the project from Xcode would that work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Somewhere in your code, you are using `Number()`. Somewhere else, you are using `SecondNumber()`. They both must exist in the view hierarchy. If they don't, then it's not clear what the point of one of them is. We need to see how they exist in the hierarchy together. They must, for example, share a common parent someone in the hierarchy.

Comment: I just updated the question with the view hierarchy showing when they are both being called. Thank you for helping me understand more about how to show the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sibling views that need to share state, that state should be controlled by the parent view. For example, this would work in your case:

```
class NumberModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstNum: String = ""
    @Published var secondNum: String = ""
    @Published var total: Int = 0
    
    func add() {
        self.total = Int(self.secondNum + self.firstNum) ?? 0
    }
}

struct Number: View {
    @ObservedObject var model : NumberModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter your first number", text: $model.firstNum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                Section {
                    Text("\(model.firstNum)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondNumber: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model : NumberModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter your second number", text: $model.secondNum)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                Section {
                    Button {
                        model.add()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Press Me!!!")
                    }
                    
                }
                Section {
                    Text("\(model.total)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var appState = NumberModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Number(model: appState)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    Text("First")
                }
            SecondNumber(model: appState)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    Text("Second")
                }
        }
    }
}
```